# Is there a jQuery plugin for making a step-by-step type presentation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was making a small thing in HTML and basically I have some "frames" like

```
<div id="frame_1">
...
</div>
<div id="frame_2">
...
</div>
...
```

Basically what I want is for only one frame to be visible at one time and to navigate between frames easily with previous and next buttons (navigation by frame number a plus, but not required)

Before I set out to write it myself I figured someone had already done it so has it been done?

Comment: Are you talking about a 'carousel'? If so, then just google 'jQuery carousel'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check this out: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/s5/ :)

Comment: It required a few style hacks to get things just how I want it (and to get syntax highlighting) but it works great and is a lot better than starting from scratch